# Excel VBA autofilter between two dates

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have a code to filter between two dates in excel vba. The problem is the autofilter seems to disregard the minimum date and only displays dates less than maximum date as the output. Please find the filter code below. Thanks for helping

```
ddate1 = UserForm4.DTPicker1.Value
ddate2 = UserForm4.DTPicker2.Value

If ddate1 >= ddate2 Then
MsgBox " Your start value is wrong", vbInformation, "Notification"
Exit Sub
Else

Sheets(1).Select
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(m, 2)).AutoFilter

Sheets(1).Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(m, 2)).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & Application.Min(ddate1, ddate2), _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & Application.Max(ddate1, ddate2)
End If
```

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `m` is correct?  Have you declared `ddate1` and `ddate2` as `Date`?  Are the values in column B of your sheet actual dates, or text that looks like dates?  (I checked your code by setting some dummy values for `ddate1` and `ddate2`, and putting some dummy date values in column B, and it filtered my dummy data so that only rows which contained dates between the two values were displayed.)

Comment: Hi, I have declared both ddate1 and 2 as dates and  m = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, that's what I used to define m and it was declared as long. So, I'm not sure why it isn't working. The output of this filter is supposed to display in a listbox in a userform. Please help

Comment: And is the data in column B actual dates, or just text that looks like a date?  If you aren't sure, write a dummy formula somewhere saying `=LEN(B8)` - if it says `5` then you probably have a real date, but if it says `10` (if the date was something like `04/06/2017`) or `8` (if it is `04/06/17`) or `11` (if it is `4 June 2017`) then it means it is text.

Comment: @YowE3k, I tried what you said. I have a few dummy data in my database. two of them gave output of 5 but one gave an output of 16. I think It saved the time or something. it is the only one that shows time when you click on the cell. In inputing those dates though, I used a date picker. What do you think is wrong? I tried adding more dates using the date picker and it adds the time too. I have to format the dates, right?

Comment: If the `LEN` is returning 16, that's possibly fine (it's probably a date of `42987.15613172` or something - Excel stores dates as a single precision number) - another test you could do would be `=MID(B8,3,1)` (assuming the 3rd displayed character is a `/`) and see whether that returns a `/` or a number.  A number would signify that it is picking up the 3rd character of something like `42987.15613172`, but a `/` would indicate it is picking up the 3rd character of the text `"09/09/2017"`.

Comment: I tried it, it returns the number 8

Comment: @YowE3K Please what do you suggest I do?

Comment: I can only suggest that you step through the code and verify that `m` and `ddate1` and `ddate2` are being set correctly.  All I can think of at this point is that `Sheets(1)` contains different numbers of populated rows in column B than `ws` contains.